# Changing an input from an integer to a string back to an integer

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a form that sends a time in the format of HH:MM:SS (10:00:00) as a string it retrieves data from a database that then displays the temperature and humidity of that time. But i would like to to be so if they entered 10am (10:00:00) it would search the database from 10:00:00 to 10:59:59. I am using sqlite3 so there is no time stamp. This is also in python.
So I'm really asking if there is a way to convert to an integer at the 00:59:59 to it then change it back to a string to use in the query. Also the time in the database is as text and the same format

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys
import cgi, cgitb

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

dateValue = form.getvalue('dateValue')
timeValue  = form.getvalue('timeValue')

con = lite.connect('/var/www/readings.db')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    if(dateValue and timeValue != None):

        cur.execute("""SELECT temperature, humidity FROM readings WHERE dateReading = ? AND timeReading = ? LIMIT 1""",(dateValue, timeValue))
        read = cur.fetchall()

        if(len(read) > 0):

            print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
            print "<html>"
            print "<head>"
            print "<title>Hello - CGI Program</title>"
            print "</head>"
            print "<body>"
            print "<h2>Temperature %s</h2>" % (read[0][0])
            print "<h2>humidity %s</h2>" % (read[0][1])
            print "</body>"
            print "</html>"
        else:
            print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
            print "<html>"
            print "<head>"
            print "<title>Hello - CGI Program</title>"
            print "</head>"
            print "<body>"
            print "<h2>No entry for that date or time</h2>"
            print "</body>"
            print "</html>"


    elif(dateValue and timeValue == None):
        print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
        print "<html>"
        print "<head>"
        print "<title>Hello - CGI Program</title>"
        print "</head>"
        print "<body>"
        print "<h2>Please enter a date or time</h2>"
        print "</body>"
        print "</html>"
```

Comment: post your code, what did you try ? You probably can resort to basic string manipulation since it seems you only need to compare the first 3 characters of both strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have the current time in String format:

```
timeString = "10:59:16"
```

You can use the `split` method to split this string at every instance of a colon (":"). This returns a list with 3 elements.

```
timeList = timeString.split(":")
print(timeList) -> ["10","59","16"]
```

You can store these elements and do whatever calculations you choose with them.

```
hours = int(timeList[0]) -> 10
minutes = int(timeList[1]) -> 59
seconds = int(timeList[2]) -> 16
```

Once you have finished your calculations, or adjusted the variables, you can combine them back into a string by concatenating.

```
timeString = str(hours) + ":" + str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds)
print(timeString) -> "10:59:16"
```

I hope this helps. Good luck Cameron!

Comment: accept my answer please :3. I am new and need to get more rep to flag and use bounties

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you could just use a [Like clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm) in your SQLite query. If your "timestamps" are strings, instead of

```
 cur.execute("""SELECT temperature, humidity FROM readings WHERE dateReading = ? AND timeReading = ? LIMIT 1""",(dateValue, timeValue))
```

use something like

```
cur.execute("""SELECT temperature, humidity FROM readings WHERE dateReading = ? AND timeReading like ? LIMIT 1""",(dateValue, '{0:02}:__:__'.format(selected_hour))
```

where `selected_hour` has been assigned the hour value selected by the user. This query should select all records that match the chosen date value and where the hour matches the chosen value.

Alternatively, I'd think

```
cur.execute("""SELECT temperature, humidity FROM readings WHERE dateReading = ? AND timeReading like ? LIMIT 1""",(dateValue, '{0:02}%'.format(selected_hour))
```

would also do the trick.